# Why is there a difference between the plot and the saved image (fontsize, linewidht)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, save, font-size

i draw measured contours and Text into an image.
When i open the plot by `plt.show()` the  `fontsize` and contours `linewidth` is how i defined it.
In the saved file (`plt.savefig`) these parameters are not passed or passed wrong. They are very large compared to the shown image.

I have changed the figure dpi and size but it hasnt worked out.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(img_blank, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
for n, contour in enumerate(cnts):
    ax.plot(contour[:, 1], contour[:, 0], linewidth=2)
ax.axis('image')
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
for i in range(0, len(mass_centres_x)):
    strs= str(i+1)
    plt.text(mass_centres_x[i],mass_centres_y[i], strs, fontsize = 5)

plt.savefig(new_name, dpi = 1200)
plt.show()
```

Alternativ the same here:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os

img_blank= 255 *np.ones(shape =[ 200, 6000, 3], dtype= np.uint8)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(img_blank, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax.axis('image')
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.text(100,100, 'lol', fontsize = 5)


#save reslut
os.chdir('Your/Folder')
new_name = "olololo.tif"
plt.savefig(new_name, dpi = 1200)
plt.show()
```

I expected the saved figure to be the same as the shown one but the `fontsize`and `linewidth` changes.[image]

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of the issue, i.e. a code that anyone can copy, paste and run and would see the same problem?

Comment: I have added a minimal reproducible example. Its my first time, hope it works. I think the reason why this problem exists is the huge image dimension in x-direction.

Comment: If I set `dpi=fig.dpi` in `savefig`, both pictures are the same. Are you sure that you set both, `figure.dpi` and `savefig.dpi` to the same value?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Both the image shown on screen and the saved image look the same.

Comment: if i set dpi = fig.dpi the test size is right but the quality is so bad that you cannot read it. It is a very large picture (x-scale) and that causes the problems. In the shown image i need to zoom to read it. seems like dpi changes while zooming. about reproducing: the latters sown are very smaler than saved. not that easy to see but true.